# Encryption on SQLite3 database - login

Tags: python, database, sqlite, authentication, encryption

I want the user of the program to make a DB and set a password on it. Then when they want to use the DB they need the password, how can i do this?
The DB doesn't just need to be encrypted when the user don't have the program opened.

I have heard of SQLcipher but I don't know if that is the best method to do what I want to do.

I have no idea about the best way to do this, if someone could give me just an pointing finger i would appreciate it.

Comment: Do you need encryption or only a password to access a db from the program ?

Comment: I need the database to be encrypted, and when the user starts the program they get asked to write an password, and if the password is correct they can view the contents of the db.